# Can't add an iOS 9.3 iPad Pro (9.7-inch) simulator in Xcode 8

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode8, ios10

I recently downloaded the Xcode 8 beta and as I was adding iOS 10 simulators, I noticed I didn't have a simulator (9.3 or 10.0) for the 9.7-inch iPad Pro. I added the iOS 10 simulator, but when I tried to add a 9.3 simulator, I saw that that wasn't an option for the iPad Pro (9.7-inch; the 12.9-inch works fine).

[image]

Is this intended, or is it a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might help you https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/44423.

Comment: Try downloading "iOS 9.3 simulator" by clicking on the 'Download more simulator runtimes.." pop up option you have on your screen shot.

Comment: all iOS 9.2 9.3 are ticked but unable to add. I am using x code 8 GM

Answer (score 1):

There's no functional difference between the iPad Pro 9.7" in the iOS 9.3 Simulator and the iPad Air 2 in the iOS 9.3 Simulator.  The differences only manifest (in the simulator) in iOS 10.  Thus, there was no reason to add it for iOS 9.3 (and Xcode 7.3).

Comment: Thanks for this, saved me a headache of figuring out why its not there